# SQL statement to produce a nested SELECT box with three levels of grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following tables in my lesson observation recording system:

[image: Observation recording - faculty structure]

- Faculties may contain one or many subjects.
- Subjects may contain one or many courses.
- Subjects may belong to one faculty.
- Courses may belong to one subject.

---

So, for example:

**Maths, Business & ICT** (faculty)

*Maths* (subject): GCSE Maths, AS Maths, A2 Maths, A2 Further Maths (courses)

*Business & ICT* (subject): GCSE Business, BTEC Business, GCSE ICT, BTEC ICT (courses)

---

I want to produce a `<SELECT>` box along these lines:

```
<select name="courses" id="courses">
    <optgroup label="Maths">
        <option value="1">GCSE Maths</option>
        <option value="2">AS Maths</option>
        <option value="3">A2 Maths</option>
        <option value="4">A2 Further Maths</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Business">
        <option value="5">GCSE Business</option>
        <option value="6">GCSE ICT</option>
        <option value="7">BTEC Business</option>
        <option value="8">BTEC ICT</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

But that box will be populated (using JavaScript) once the user has first selected one of the **faculties**.

So, ideally, I'd like to retrieve all of this information with a single SQL statement - a list of all faculties, then nested subjects and nested courses. I will be using PHP to process this information and I'm comfortable with that.

Is this possible in a single statement? I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
f.Title AS Faculty,
s.Title AS Subject,
c.Title AS Course
FROM
Faculties f
LEFT JOIN Subjects s ON f.Faculty_ID = s.Faculty_ID
LEFT JOIN Courses c ON s.Subject_ID = c.Subject_ID
```

Comment: That's the right information, but I think I'm looking for some kind of grouping. No idea if that's even possible in MySQL however..

Comment: Sure you can group in SQL, but then you will lose information. The grouping you are looking will have to be done in PHP.